# Centos Suphp , How do  I get Alias with Phpmyadmin working

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, alias, suphp

I have configured my CentOS installation with Apache with suPHP. It works very well.
But when I install PHPMyAdmin I get a permissions problem. 
Because PHPMyAdmin is located under `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.
I do not want to use an extra vhost for every domain. 
I want to use an Alias on each domain to  `/phpmyadmin`.

What I must do to get it working?

Comment: What sort of permissions problem do you have? Just guessing here, but you may have selinux enabled. What is the result of running getenforce?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that. I solve this problem by adding a new site dedicated to PhpMyadmin for all the users

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a system to hand to test this on (sorry) but I think you can use the `docroot` directive in your suphp.conf file to provide a path that all php scripts have to be in e.g.

```
docroot=/var/www:${HOME}/public_html:/usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

may work.